# How to uninstall dotnet core on azure app?

Tags: azure, .net-core

I installed dotnet core 2.0.1 on the web app container by accident, I just want to uninstall it now so my app can run, how can I go back to 1.0.4? My app is hosted on Azure Web app.

Comment: I would imagine deleting it and creating from scratch would help ;)

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have ssl certificate and extensions so i prefer not to go through so much work..

Comment: If you have configured backup in Azure you can get a previous version of your app.

Comment: @DmitryKazakov I didn't :/

Comment: Did you publish the updated app to Azure slot using VS? Do you have source code/source control?

Comment: @DmitryKazakov currently using the B2 basic and deployment slots seem to be unavailable. I'm using Github integration for azure and ( Deployment options ) tab

Comment: @Hristo If you don't have the source code or your app with 1.0.4 in Git repository I would suggest to contact Microsoft support. As far as I know Azure cloud does automatic backups for some days/weeks and support can help you to recover the app.

Comment: @DmitryKazakov I have the source code, but the container itself has the 2.0.1 version so it runs the app with the latest version of .net core.. how can I instruct the container to run 1.0.4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147094/discussion-between-dmitry-kazakov-and-hristo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications can specify the runtime version they wish to use. This is done in the csproj. You can find more information about this specific feature here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```